# Angular rerouting to home page doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, import, angular-routing

Here is my error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
```

This is the code from the view.html:

```
<div class="container">
  This is the main app;
  <a routerLink="second">Click to go to second</a>
  <a routerLink="third">Click to go to third</a>
  <a routerLink="app">Go to Home</a>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And this is my array of objects which includes the path to the home and other paths. The path to the home is correct, hence I don't see why the error pops up every time I click on it.

```
const appRoutes: Routes=[
  {path:'second', component:SecondComponent},
  {path:'third', component:ThirdComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'./app', pathMatch:'full'},
]
```

When I click on the third and second component url, everything works fine.

**NOTE:** I want to hide the second and third component when I click on the home component.

Comment: You have used `routerLink="home"` but did not create a route for it. Do so and check.

Comment: I've changed it but things stay the same. I just want to display the home page with the other components being "erased". How can I achieve that?

Comment: Any changes in error? If not, change `<a routerLink="app">Go to Home</a>` to `<a routerLink="">Go to Home</a>` and check.

Comment: @abhig10 I've done that but the problem is that I'm on localhost 4200 and when I do that my home page just duplicates like this: localhost:4200/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem, my home path is empty and therefor the home page does not duplicate itself once I click on the home tag.

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes=[
  {path:'first', component:FirstComponent},
  {path:'second', component:SecondComponent},
  {path:'third', component:ThirdComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'', pathMatch:'full'},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the home route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes=[
  {path:'home', component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'second', component:SecondComponent},
  {path:'third', component:ThirdComponent},
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'**', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'}
];
```

Comment: This, agian, just duplicates my home page when i press on my home link

Comment: This is the right way to achieve this. If it doesn't work as expected, the problem is not in the routing but in the views/components implementation. Anyway the code snippet in your question does not provide enough information to help you with that